# updating project made with node v6 to node v10

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a node project made with node v6 and I want to upgrade this project to 
node v10+ .
How should I start ?

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-67\fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE\node_modules\fibers/build
C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:20
        throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
        ^

Error: Missing binary. See message above.
```

Comment: This seems to be an error with the `fibers` Node module. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: Try updating `fibers` module, try removing `node_modules` directory and running `npm i` afterwards to redownload everything.

Comment: There are 5 vulnerabilities :                                                              
found 5 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 1 high) in 310 scanned packages
  5 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.

Comment: Then you're likely using an old version of some package, that is still vulnerable to some exploits. At this point, you'd probably want to update Node *and* some packages. Does it still not work?

Comment: My node version is : ( v11.6.0 ) and My npm version is: ( 6.5.0-next.0 ) .. these are the packages on my machine. should I update them globally or in the project and what command line can I use because some commands didn't succeed?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I meant updating the packages listed in the `package.json` file in your project directory. So it still doesn't work? Or did updating `fibers` fix at least your initial problem?

Comment: I updated the dependencies in package.json file and this is the result : {C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE>npm install
added 33 packages from 29 contributors, removed 28 packages, updated 18 packages, moved 1 package and audited 330 packages in 17.918s
found 5 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details}

Comment: and still doesn't work with this NEW error message : {C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE\middleware\logger.js:11
const logger = new winston.Logger({
               ^
TypeError: winston.Logger is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AbolfadL\Desktop\BE\middleware\logger.js:11:16)}